# Enthalpy-Internal Energy Conservation in an Open System

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, energy-conservation

In preparation for the FE, I've come across a thermodynamic scenario in *Michael R. Lindeburg, PE*'s review manual that I cannot seem to wrap my head around.  Though I have a full solution to the following problem, it is the conceptual logic surrounding the transfer of enthalpy into internal energy that I cannot grasp.

**In short:** Steam with negligible velocity is allowed into a rigid, insulated tank with zero initial absolute pressure and zero elevation change.  Once the tank is full, the temperature of the steam has nearly doubled.  **How is this possible?**  If the final internal energy of the gas is increased, the enthalpy must also increase, and I fail to see where the added energy comes from.  The solution suggests that the initial enthalpy is converted to internal energy, but the enthalpy must increase proportionally.  I am at a loss.

**For those interested in the entire problem:**

*Statement*

The absolute pressure in a rigid, insulated tank is initially zero.  The tank volume is 0.04 m^3.  The tank and steam inlet are at the same elevation.  A valve is opened allowing 250°C and 600 kPa steam with negligible velocity to slowly fill the tank.  Most nearly, what is the temperature of the steam in the tank after the tank is full.

*Solution*

Use the First Law of Thermodynamics for Open Systems.  The control volume is the tank.  Subscript $s$ refers to the substance in the tank.  Subscript $i$ refers to the tank inlet, at the valve.  The tank does not have an exit, so all subscript $e$ variables are zero.  Subscript $1$ refers to what is initially in the tank.  Since the tank is initially evacuated, it has no contents, so all subscript $1$ variables are zero. Subscript $2$ refers to the steam in the tank after filling.  Since the tank is insulated, $Q_{in}$ is zero.  There is no work done on or by the steam, so $W_{net}$ is zero.  Although pressure does not appear explicitly in the First Law equation, the final pressure in the tank is $p_2 = p_i$.

$$\sum\left(\dot{m}_i\left(h_i + \dfrac{v_i^2}{2} + g z_i\right)\right) - \sum\left(\dot{m}_e\left(h_e + \dfrac{v_e^2}{2} + g z_e\right)\right) + \dot{Q}_{in} - \dot{W}_{net} = \dfrac{\partial(m_s u_s)}{\partial t}$$

$$\begin{align}
m_i h_i &= m_2 u_2 - m_1 u_1 \\
m_i h_i &= m_2 u_2
\end{align}$$

Use a mass balance to relate $m_i$ to $m_2$:

$$\begin{align}
\sum m_i - \sum m_e &= (m_2 - m_1)_{system} \\
m_i &= m_2
\end{align}$$

Combine the two equations and solve for the internal energy of the system:

$$u = h_i = 2957.2\text{ kJ/kg}$$

250°C, 600 kPa steam is superheated.  From the superheated steam table, its enthalpy is $h = 2957.2\text{ kJ/kg}$.  Since this is the final internal energy of the steam in the tank, interpolate to find the temperature of superheated steam with $u = 2957.2\text{ kJ/kg}$:

$$T = 397.0°C$$

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here are two things.  First the steam enters through the valve, and experiences viscous heating within the valve which largely cancels out the expansion cooling it would otherwise have experienced.  Then, once in the tank, the steam in the tank is recompressed nearly adiabatically and reversibly (by the new gas entering behind it), so that its temperature now increases.

Comment: I found that the increase in the internal energy of the steam in the chamber exactly equals the $pv$ term of the initial  enthalpy of the steam,. This suggested to me that the increase in internal energy  of the steam is due to flow work done on the steam moving it into the chamber. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting the results of my calculation?

Comment: That’s the decompression I was referring to.

Comment: The newly entering steam recompresses the steam in the tank that entered before it.

Comment: So, is it then correct to say that the increase in internal energy (and temperature) of the steam is due to the $v\Delta p$ flow work  moving the steam into the chamber? That's the way it works out mathematically.

Comment: I don’t think so.  I think it the delta Pv work done by the outside steam pushing steam ahead of it in.

Comment: So in this case, $\Delta (pv)$ is $p_{f}v_{f}-p_{i}v_{i}$ and $p_{i}v_{i}=0$ in the chamber?

Comment: External steam is acting like a piston and causing an amount of work equal to $Pv\Delta n$, where $\Delta n$ is the number of moles of steam pushed into the tank.

Comment: Thanks Chet. Your answer to the OP explains the reason for the increase in internal energy. But I think the OP still wonders where the energy comes from, ie, needs to see the math. I drafted something but perhaps you want to take a crack at it instead

Comment: @BobD No, I think you analysis is fine.

Comment: I thought I had it figured out and drafted an answer, but then I started having doubts. I could use your counsel, but it would probably be better in Chat, or some other forum, if you have the time. If you don't have the time, I understand. Thanks. Bob

Comment: Yes.  Let's do a chat.  Do you know how to start one?

Comment: I've done it once. I'll give it a shot again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Chet. I drafted and posted an answer and subsequently deleted it after having some doubts. I think you can see the deleted answer. Here is my doubt. What if we consider the contents of the tank and the steam outside the tank together as an isolated system. if the steam outside the tank does $pv$ work reversibly and adiabatically  compressing the steam in the tank there is no heat transfer and no external work done on the system. As such the change in internal energy and temperature (if we can consider the steam an ideal gas) of the system would be zero. What's wrong with my thinking?

Comment: @BobD The system you described can be analyzed using the closed system version of the 1st law.  The initial volume of this system is equal to the tank volume plus the volume of the n moles of gas that enter the tank:  $V=V_T+nv$. The final volume of this system is just $V_T$.  So the change in volume of this system is $\Delta V=(V_T+nv)-V_T=nv$.  And the work done by the steam external to this system is $P\Delta V=nPv$So the change in internal energy of this n moles of steam (the system) is $$\Delta U=n\Delta u=nPv$$

Comment: Tried to create a room. Got nowhere. Said a room already existed. But I couldn't find it. Very frustrating.

Comment: We can always reconvene in PhysicsForums.com, in a Conversation or in a regular thread.  Just a thought.

Comment: That would be great using the Physics Forum. I think I may still be a member from last time we worked together, though its been a while.

Comment: You're still a member.  So please get us started.

Comment: Got into the "Other Physics Topics" forum where we previously communicated. I see a "start thread" option, but don't see a "Conversation" option. Not even sure what the difference is. Which do you think is more applicable? And if I started it, how are you notified? I'm not familiar with starting this since last time you initiated. Just need some guidance on how to get this rolling.

Comment: It's up to you.  If you want to do it in a conversation, just click on the envelope on the tool bar at top of the page.  My user name is chestermiller.  If you want to do it in a thread so that others can also chime in, then start the thread by clicking on Post Thread and then, in your text, ping me with @ followed by my user name.